# Account Permissions With TFS Build Service

Tags: iis, tfs, windows-server-2008, tfsbuild

I have two servers with TFS installed, one that runs the build service, and one that has the main repository.  In order to have an account on a windows domain to run as the build service, what permissions do I need to give him in windows?  I'm trying to use a newly created account, but am having registration issues, and I'm not sure if its windows permissions related or IIS related...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

- The person configuring the build server - To perform this procedure, you must be a member of the Administrators group on the build machine and your Manage build resources permission must be set to Allow. For more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx#perms

  - Before a build machine can build projects in a given team project collection, you must configure the collection with the build service account for that build machine. First, you identify the account under which Team Foundation Build Service is running on the build machine. Then, on the application-tier server that hosts the collection, you add the account to the Project Collection Build Service Accounts group for that collection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668757.aspx

It is strongly recommended that you use the service account rather than NT Authority\Network Service.

HTH
Cheers, Tarun

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use NT Authority\Network service

Comment: Not if the server also acts as a domain controller.